# How can I prevent super glue from getting on my fingers?

Tags: comfort, efficiency, adhesive, repair

I was just wondering if anyone knew of anyway that I could manage to prevent getting super glue on my fingers while using it. I need to use super glue to fix a few things that my children have broken but I ABSOLUTELY CAN NOT STAND when my finger get super glue on them and then they pretty much get super glued together! Is there any kind of oil or anything I could put in my fingers to prevent the super use from sticking?

Comment: A simple Web search for 'removing superglue' produced several different methods—the most common by using fingernail polish remover or acetone applied on a cotton ball to soak the attached surfaces.

Comment: @Stan Acetone barely works. It takes at least ten minutes of rubbing and futzing. It's not a proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to avoid getting superglue or Krazyglue™ is by using rubber gloves or finger clots to avoid contact. If something goes wrong, you can toss them.
[image: Finger clots]
Finger clots are great because they are tight-fitting, cheap, and maintain a good grip on most any surface while repairing even small parts. They are available in latex or nitrile if you are allergic to latex.

Answer (score 1):

Don't oil your fingers because

- won't be able to handle the toys you want to mend
- the glue will not stick

So wear disposable gloves, such as these.

[image]

<sup>*Images from Amazon*</sup>

Available online, or at builders merchants, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to apply the superglue directly on the object you're gluing.

Instead, get an old newspaper. Make a blob of glue on the newspaper. Dip the object in this blob, then wipe off the excess on the newspaper. Then glue the parts together.

With this method, you're far less likely to apply excess glue, so less chance of glue being pushed out of the seam as you press the parts together.

You can also use pliers, tweezers etc. to hold the parts instead of your fingers.

Comment: Another way to control the glue more easily than directly from the tube, is to use a matchstick or other disposable tool, to dip into the mentioned blob and transfer to the mending site.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I prevent super glue from getting on my fingers?**

If petroleum jelly can be used as home remedy to break super glue bonds, it might be effective as a preventative measure when using krazy glue and accidentally getting it on your fingers.

> [image: petroleum jelly]
>
> Super Glue Corp also lists petroleum jelly as a home remedy to break super glue bonds. Just massage the petroleum jelly into the skin until it is loose. It can be an effective solution on how do you get crazy glue off your fingers. - [33 Ways You Haven’t Tried to Remove Super Glue](https://www.familyhandyman.com/list/25-ways-you-havent-tried-to-remove-super-glue/) (See number 7)

Answer (score 0):

Finger cots. (Amazon)  I've used them for years for all types of jobs.
They're also perfect for added grip when handling mirrors, glass etc. The uses are endless.